# Ubuntu throws this error: error found when loading /home/user/.profile

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, error-handling

I'm using ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

The error occurs after entering my user.

This is the description of the error:

```
error found when loading /home/user/.profile

tput: no value for $TERM and no -T specified 
tput: no value for $TERM and no -T specified 
tput: no value for $TERM and no -T specified 
tput: no value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

[image]

Comment: what does "entering your profile" mean, exactly?

Comment: @MarcusMüller putting my password on the user 'davi'

Comment: Did it ever work before? If so, what did you do before it stopped working?

Comment: @U.Windl yes he work before, I dont really know what I did that make he stop but I found the reason behind the error: my ´.bashrc´ was empty, so I just had to "make" a new one.

Comment: So the problem was not `.profile`, but an empty `.bashrc`? On SUSE systems the `TERM` is set in `/etc/profile` with something like `test -z "${TERM}" && { TERM=linux; export TERM; }`.

Comment: @U.Windl yes probably to load the '.profile' he needs the '.bashrc' working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason behind the error: my ´.bashrc´ was empty, so I just had to "make" a new one.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had the following line at the beginning of .bachrc (got hacked by a colleague...)

```
curl https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Pun?format=txt
```

I moved it to the end of .bash_rc and it works fine (removing also works, but I actually like it).

Answer (score 0):

As is common with unix programs, they output their name as part of the error message. So in this case the error is coming from the `tput` command.

`tput` is used to set up terminals, for example if your terminal has programmable tab settings it can set them up. These days most people no longer need it.

In order to set up your terminal it needs to know what kind of terminal you have. You can tell it either by passing the `-T` argument with a value or by setting the `TERM` environment variable. However you appear to have done neither, so you are getting the error message.

The simplest thing to do is add a line

```
export TERM; TERM=vt100
```

as the **first** line of `/home/davi/.profile`. it will hard code a terminal type which is almost certain to work for you.

Comment: this should under no circumstances be necessary, and it also should not be done unless your terminal is actually vt100 compatible.

Comment: @MarcusMüller is correct, by default it is setup by `/etc/profile` or one of the files in `/etc/profile.d` for every user logging in to the machine

Comment: @Lockszmith From the question it is clear that TERM is not defined. Your comment saying in effect that it should be defined doesn't help the original poster. Typically this would not be defined where you suggest. Originally, when you had physical terminals connected to serial ports, the type of the terminal was set in /etc/ttys. Once you had dial-up modems then the system administrator (who controls /etc/profile) should **not** presume to know better than the user what kind of terminal the user has in front of them. Using vt100 is a pragmatic choice, almost everything uses a superset of it.

Comment: @icarus I added my comment to indicate where the logic usually is implemented. This can send anyone interested to inspect where this comes from in some major distribution - where some reasonable defaults / auto-detection is performed and how. Original posting at this time is not that relevant since it's from many months ago, so at this point it is more to add missing pieces of knowledge for a "fuller picture". I probably could have been more verbose about that.